# How does virtualenv work with packages?

Tags: python, macos, path, virtualenv, env

I'm really confused with how virtualenv deals with packages. I'm on OSX and installed python2 and 3 with Homebrew followed by `pip install virtualenv`.

in terminal:

```
cd Virtualenv/MyTestEnv
. bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

would install numpy into my virtualenv folder which can only be accessed if I run my program within that env. From what I read, it does this by modifying the system *$PATH*.
However when I try running a program with numpy I can't:

```
(MyTestEnv)___________________
| ~/desktop/Python @ My-MBP (chronologos) 
| => ./wordsrt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wordsrt.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

the program has only two lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy
```

And when I do `pip list` numpy is shown as installed? Is it a problem with the hashbang?
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: First, `$PATH` is irrelevant to where the site-packages go and are found; that's what the shell uses to find executables. `$PYTHONPATH` is what specifies the starting values for Python's `sys.path`.

Comment: However, it's possible that you are somehow running the system-wide `pip` instead of the virtualenv's `pip`. If you're using a recent-enough version, I believe it can detect that you're running the system `pip` while inside a virtualenv and either give you an error/warning or install into the virtualenv anyway, so… are you using `pip` 1.5? If not, try upgrading that first.

Comment: Also, remember that OS X already comes with its own Python 2.7, so by installing another one via Homebrew, you're opening a can of worms you may not want to deal with. For example, the first `pip` on your path can easily be the Apple Python 2.7 `pip`, while `python` is the Homebrew Python 2.7 (especially since both installations like to install scripts into `/usr/local/bin`, and Python's standard attempt to disambiguate—giving `python2.7` and `pip-2.7` and similar names—doesn't help when they're both 2.7). So, if you don't actually need the Homebrew 2.7, I'd uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys. I posted what I did below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.

Firstly I modified my bashrc to only allow pip when virtualenv is on:

```
# pip should only run if there is a virtualenv currently activated
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
# cache pip-installed packages to avoid re-downloading
export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip/cache
syspip(){
   PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
```

Then to ensure user-installed binaries take precedence I added this to my bash_profile
`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Another way to run python from the virtualenv that to me feels more natural is

```
MyTestEnv/bin/python wordsrt.py
```

Try this.